# (Material UI / Next.js) Stop useStyles from Server Side Rendering

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I am currently working on a page within my application that needs access to the window object on styling.

I understand that for a component that should not be rendered on the server simply using `<NoSsr>` does it. But when accessing the window from useStyles this is called before the `render()` function. Meaning as soon as `classes=useStyles()` is hit the error: `ReferenceError: window is not defined` persists.

Any idea on how to stop the useStyles call from rendering on the server ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(answering myself)

Found a solution that works in this context:

1. Use `<NoSSr>`around the components that should have access to the global window object.
2. use `style={{}}` on the object instead of the global styling with `useStyles()` and `className`.
3. if the Theme needs to be accessed use `const theme = useTheme()` importend from `@material-ui/styles`